# vertical index match summation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Sample Sheet]

How can I get the summation of all the cells in column B given the value in column A. Let's say I want to get the summation of all the values in column B for value "1000" in column A.

Is this possible? What I've tried so far is using SUM, INDEX, and MATCH functions but I'm only able to get the first cell data.

```
SUM(INDEX(A1:B8, MATCH("1000",A1:A8, 0), 2))
```

Anyone who has some hints for me? Thanks!

Comment: `=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,1000)`.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks! It worked like a charm! if you can put your comment as an answer, I'd gladly accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, someone like me who is not that adept to excel might just bump into this problem. In any case, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should use `SUMIFS` (or its cousin `SUMIF`, which is slightly inferior):

```
=SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple:

For 1000: `=SUMIF(A1:A8, "=1000", B1:B8)`

For 2000: `=SUMIF(A1:A8, "=2000", B1:B8)`

That results in:

`82.3`

`399.39`

Comment: The `=` and `""` around the criterion are superfluous.

Comment: Interesting I always just type out the comparison, but you are right for an exact value it's not needed. "=1000" is the same as just 1000.